# Unable to echo in php each time a for loop iterates?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have a PHP script process.php that basically pings either a single host by name or IP and or a range of IPs.  The IP(s) are passed via a form.php and I'm happy to report that it works well.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
1. Output to the form each IP as it is pinged, currently the script completes before it outputs. This isn't an issue for the single IP or hostname but for the IP range it leaves the user hanging.
```

My question is can I do this with JQuery/Ajax keeping the logic within PHP and process.php or do I need to move the logic to form.php within JQuery/Ajax?

I know I haven't included the actual code but I just need a check on the logic.

```
for ($ip=$formipstart;$ip<=formipend;$ip++) {
  echo "$ip";
}
```

Comment: Yes. No. I don't know.

Comment: You can do either. There is no right answer here. Welcome to programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave it as is, but I would move your logic into web page, specially if you are good with jQuery and AJAX. For me it is always nicer to present visitor that something happens in background, to show an overlay and spinner somewhere, no matter if that takes 2 seconds or 2 minutes. It will always look better and it may save your hosting resources. For example, you can limit ping-check to 1 per second, or you can stop pinging any time, which is not possible with PHP.

Comment: I moved the logic to the form page, most of it rewritten in jquery/javascript but a portion of it is still php albeit in the form page. This left me with just the exec() and results in the processing.php page. After reading plenty of other post it would seem that with all the logic left in the process.php, that process.php page would need to finish processing before it would output. I'm only at the start of my learning but appreciate advice. To conclude I now have achieved what I set out to do.

Answer (score 0):

So my question was kind of general on where I should put the logic to achieve a ping response for each request as it happens. My first attempt was a simple form that posted to a process.php page. All the logic was contained within the process.php. The ping tool worked great but for one thing. I couldn't get ping to output as they happened. It would only output the results after the entire logic/page had been processed. The output was correct but it did leave the user hanging.

After creating this post my second attempt moved the logic to the form.php page and was rewritten in a mix of jquery and php. The form.php called the process.php which had been reduced to just the actual ping and result. With jquery and ajax I was able to show each ping response as it happened.

Annoyingly after read many more posts it would seem that if the logic was kept in process.php as pure php i would have to wait until the page has finished processing. I'm yet to see evidence showing me otherwise. It's also a pain that so much logic/code is now visible to the end user.